# doctrine does not generate columns in migrations

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I`m little bit confused. I've generated my Entity class by `bin/console make:entity` with columns `id, title` and etc. When I run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`, doctrine created me migrations. But do not create any another columns besides Id? where is my problem? Symfony 4, Postgres 11

Comment: could you post your entity?

Comment: So I removed the project and create a new one, and the problem has gone. I think It was like an recognized problem.